# Ajax validation post error html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to code chat box with ajax, but when I make the call, the php file shatbox.php doesn't appear. Here is the code and the GitHubDiff.

[GitHubb Diff](https://github.com/hunter2020/jschat/commit/f9c8658c56db2386357154cf9246a1df9b0d8cff?diff=unified#diff-2f86cb96a0233e7cb3b6f03ad573be0b)

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').on('click',function(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var shout = $('#shout').val();
  var date = getDate();
  var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&shout=' + shout + '&date' + date;

  // validation
  if(name == '' || shout == ''){
   alert('please fill Your name and shout');
  }else{
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../jschat/shoutbox.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $('#shout ul').prepend(html);
    }
   });
  }

  return false ;
 });
});
function getDate(){
 var date;
 date = new date;
 date = date.getUTCFullYear() +'-'+
  ('00' + (date.getUTCMonth() +1 )).slice(-2)+'-'+
  ('00' + date.getUTCDate().slice(-2)+' '+
  ('00' + date.getUTCHours().slice(-2)+ ':'+
  ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes().slice(-2)+':'+
  ('00' + date.getUTCSeconds().slice(-2);
 return date;
}
```

Comment: any error in dev console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 errors in the function `getDate`:

1.`Date` object is case-sensitive

2.There are some missing closing parentheses starting from `date.getUTCMonth`

```
function getDate() {
    var date = new Date;
    date = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
        ('00' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
        ('00' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
        ('00' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
        ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
        ('00' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
    return date;
}
```

This may be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

file location seems to be the issue

```
url:"../jschat/shoutbox.php",
```

try this

```
url:"../shoutbox.php",
```